# How to add joins in Inner join eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table

```
user_access_rights
user_id    access_right_id
1          1
1          2
1          3
```

And other table is

```
access_rights
ar_id       access_right
1           add
2           update
3           delete
```

One user can have many access rights. It can easily be done by queries. But I want to know the Eloquent version.

In `User_access_right` model I wrote

```
public function rights()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User_access_right')
}
```

it doesn't give me the right results and neither does get me the `access_right` column from `access_rights` table. Can someone tell and explain?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Users` Model write this:

```
public function access_rights(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\access_rights', 'user_access_rights', 'user_id', 'access_right_id');
}
```

And in your `access_rights` model add this:

```
public function user_rights(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_access_rights', 'access_right_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Then you can query like this:

**get user rights** : Auth::user()->access_rights()->get()